# When retrieving mail with IMAP I get strange text format

Tags: php, imap

I'm using IMAP to get my mails from Gmail. It works fine but when I look to the mail header it's text with strange symbols. I already tried to confert it with Imap_qprint but this doens't work for all the symbols.

```
<?php

    // Connecting to IMAP
    $mailboxPath    = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
    $username       = "mailadress";
    $password       = "password";

    $mailStream = imap_open($mailboxPath, $username, $password) or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

    // Number of mails
    $mails = imap_num_msg($mailStream);  

    // Cycle trough mails
    for($i=1; $i<=$mails; $i++) {

        // Get headerinfo mail
        $headerinfo = imap_headerinfo($mailStream, $i);

        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($headerinfo);
        // echo "</pre>";

        // Select subject out headerinfo
        $subject = $headerinfo->subject;

        $subject = quoted_printable_decode($subject);

        echo $subject . "<br>"; 

    }
```

Gives me subjects like this:

=?UTF-8?Q?New_from_Codecademy:_Introdu?= =?UTF-8?Q?ction_to_Data_Analysis_=F0=9F=94=8D_=F0=9F=93=88?=

When is use quoted_printable_decode() function it already clear up a bit but still not complete. Here how it looks than:

=?UTF-8?Q?New_from_Codecademy:_Introdu?= =?UTF-8?Q?ction_to_Data_Analysis__?

How can I convert this to:

New from Codecademy: Introduction to Data Analysis

Comment: @Quentin This is not quite a duplicate.  QP encoding in headers is a bit different than QP encoding in bodies (as it has Encoded Word baggage as well), and that function does not work completely on headers.

Comment: Quentin I have changed the question, end stil you duplicate it.